# How to fix JSON format issue in JAVA?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-boot

This is my 1st project in java spring. So i m trying to figure out the best way to do things.

I have several Rest Apis in my project for which different kinds of API response will be sent.

Somewhere i m getting data in List Format, somewhere else another format. So i m trying to figure out the best way to send response in JSON format.

One of the API Response i have is this:

```
{
"result": "true",
"message": null,
"data": "{\"id\":1,\"firstName\":\"test\",\"lastName\":\"test\",\"emailId\":\"test@test.com\",\"mobileNo\":\"1234567890\",\"alternateMobileNo\":\"1234567890\",\"username\":\"test\",\"password\":\"7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b\",\"status\":\"active\",\"userRole\":\"test\",\"dateCreated\":\"Feb 6, 2019\",\"permissions\":\"\"}"
}
```

My biggest issue is the formatting of data key in the above JSON.

This is my controller action:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/staff/get", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public Map get(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters) {
    Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Staff staff = new Staff();

    staff.setId(new Integer(parameters.get("id")));

    List validateToken = loginAuthTokenService.validateToken(new Integer(request.getHeader("loginId")), request.getHeader("loginType"), request.getHeader("token"));
    if (validateToken.size() > 0) {
        Staff staffDetails = staffService.getStaff(staff.getId());
        response.put("result", "true");
        response.put("data", gson.toJson(staffDetails));
    } else {
        response.put("result", "false");
        response.put("message", "No records found.");
    }
    return response;
}
```

Should I create a separate Class for sending API Response or anyone please guide me the proper way of sending response.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Gson#toJson(Object)` returns a String and that String is mapped as JSON key in your map.

You don't have to convert your object to a JSON, Spring will do it for you (it uses Jackson as JSON mapper so you don't have add Gson dependency to your project.

A simple and working implementation could be something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/staff/get", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> get(
        @RequestParam("id") Integer id,
        @RequestHeader("loginId") Integer loginId,
        @RequestHeader("loginType") String loginType, 
        @RequestHeader("token") String token) {

    List validateToken = loginAuthTokenService.validateToken(loginId, loginType, token);
    if (!validateToken.isEmpty()) {
        Stuff stuff = staffService.getStaff(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(stuff);
    }

    return ResponseEntity.notFound().body("No records found.");
}
```

---

Also consider to not return a *generic* map from your method, but the `Stuff` object your front-end needs. In case of failure you should return a failure object with a specific http response code (e.g. 404, 400, 500...).

Take a look at [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring).

Comment: If i will do this, how will i send response.put("result", "true"); since "true" is not an object?

Comment: `"true"` is a String, a String is an Object. By the way, take a look at my last edit to the answer.

Comment: I see, but @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK) i will have to use above the function, how do i send different kinds of response based on data available or not like i did true/false ?

Comment: Either by returning a [ResponseEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) with proper http code or throwing an exception in your method and using a ControllerAdvise to handle it like the linked guide says (there plenty of guides, I just linked you the first I found in Google)

Comment: Here, [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-rest-service-exception-handling-1) may be better

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Let me try to implement.

Answer (score 0):

To format the the data attribute , you can store it in a map :-

```
Map<String, Object> map1= new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

and is you have multiple data attributes you can create an ArrayList of Maps :-

```
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> dataClerk = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
```

I had a similar usecas so i used the below code :-

```
obj = parser.parse(response);
JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject)parser.parse(response); 
JSONArray jsonarr_1 = (JSONArray) jobj.get(item);
for(int i=0 ;i<jsonarr_1.size();i++) {
        Map<String, Object> entry = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        org.json.simple.JSONObject temp= (org.json.simple.JSONObject) 
        jsonarr_1.get(i);
        Set<String> attributes= temp.keySet();
        for(String s: attributes) {
                entry.put(s, temp.get(s));
             }

    }
```